# Filter system defined tables in sql developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c

I am following a tutorial on oracle and i just created my oracle datababase.

However i am seeing all these redundant tables, my db was not a container database by the way.

[image]

What is this stuff all about? why is it there?

So as it says in the comment this is what you normally see if you login with System account.I created a new account and logged in with that and all is fine.

Comment: Who are you logged in as? It looks like you're logged in as SYS. Don't do that. Login as your application schema owner - then you'll see the 'regular' tables, and not the ones the database uses to manage the database.

Answer (score 0):

From [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/CNCPT/data-dictionary-and-dynamic-performance-views.htm#CNCPT1209)

> An important part of an Oracle database is its data dictionary, which
>   is a read-only set of tables that provides administrative metadata
>   about the database.
>
> A data dictionary contains information such as the following:
>
> - The definitions of every schema object in the database, including
>     default values for columns and integrity constraint information
> - The amount of space allocated for and currently used by the schema
>     objects
> - The names of Oracle Database users, privileges and roles granted to
>     users, and auditing information related to users (see "User Accounts")
>
> The data dictionary is a central part of data management for every
>   Oracle database. For example, the database performs the following
>   actions:
>
> - Accesses the data dictionary to find information about users, schema
>     objects, and storage structures
> - Modifies the data dictionary every time that a DDL statement is issued
>     (see "Data Definition Language (DDL) Statements")
>
> Because Oracle Database stores data dictionary data in tables, just
>   like other data, users can query the data with SQL. For example, users
>   can run SELECT statements to determine their privileges, which tables
>   exist in their schema, which columns are in these tables, whether
>   indexes are built on these columns, and so on.

For example:

```
SQL> select count(1) from user_tables;

  COUNT(1)
----------
       167

SQL> create table oneMoreTable(a number);

Table created.

SQL> select count(1) from user_tables;

  COUNT(1)
----------
       168
SQL> select count(distinct table_name), count(1) from user_tab_columns;

COUNT(DISTINCTTABLE_NAME)   COUNT(1)
------------------------- ----------
                      172        465

SQL> drop table oneMoreTable;

Table dropped.

SQL> select count(distinct table_name), count(1) from user_tab_columns;

COUNT(DISTINCTTABLE_NAME)   COUNT(1)
------------------------- ----------
                      171        464
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually, these are tables that "belong" to the database - either because they are owned by one of the predefined users (SYS,SYSTEM,SYSDBA ...) or because Oracle uses them for housekeeping, e.g. for

- fulltext indices (these are named DR$... )
- materialized view logs (these are named RUPD$... and MLOG$...)

Apart Tables that contain the prefix `V$` are tables that store volatile information.These tables are also called `dynamic performance` tables.

Volatile information is produced by an oracle instance while it is in use (In use means the instance is up and running). Volatile Information includes Statistics, session information of users, memory allocation.